# Samsung Galaxy S3 doesn't respond to some secret codes

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, system, dialer-codes

Samsung Galaxy S3 I9300 doesn't respond to all secret codes in [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2098642) . Specially it can restart with non of the codes in the list. Do I have a fake Galaxy S3 ?

Answer (score 1):

"Dialer Codes" are divided into multiple categories:

- **[USSD and supplementary service Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supplementary_service_codes):** network specific, should work on any device ("device independent")
- **manufacturer specific codes:** specific to devices of a given manufacturer
- **device-specific codes:** as the name says, specific to a given device
- **system-specific codes:** specific to a given device configuration

What you are facing, most likely belongs to one of the last two categories. The Galaxy phones come in different variants: area-specific ones, and international versions. So those can be counted as different devices, or at least different systems, as they not only have slight differences in their hardware, but most likely also different modifications in their software; hence at least not all "sytem-specific codes" will work on all the different "variants".

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I have found #*2562#, #*3849#, #*3851# and #*3876# codes in many sites but none of them restart my phone. I have a I9300.

Comment: Please read the last paragraph again. This is probably a system-specific code, so it works in very specific combinations (device hardware, Android version, and some more specifics might be involved). I cannot tell you how to make any of those codes work, nor do I know a code that would do. But you could long-press the power button, and select "restart" from the power menu – which is a much easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have your answer directly on the link : "only a few are working".

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have found #*2562#, #*3849#, #*3851# and #*3876# codes in many sites but none of them restart my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't trust such a list of secret codes, as Izzy mentionned.
If you want to have a valid list of secret codes available on your device , you should use an automated secret codes crawler.

I recently developped an Open Source app that crawls AndroidManifest.xml files on your device to found secret codes, and allows you to execute the secret codes available on your device.
You can get it on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.simon.marquis.secretcodes) or on the GitHub repository [Android-Secret Codes](https://github.com/SimonMarquis/Android-SecretCodes).

But keep in mind that sometimes, secret codes are just executing themselves silently (without visual hint)

Comment: Please see my [comment here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/78608/16575), Simon. You might wish to update your answers accordingly then, concerning the "full list" ;) But agreed, OP seems to specifically care about "group 4" (system-specific codes, i.e. ROM+apps), so your solution should be fine.