# Entering Samsung Codes on the Galaxy S4 - Verizon

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung, verizon, dialer-codes

This is likely an embarrassing question, but I may not be the only one struggling.

I am trying to figure out a problem with my phone by using these secret dialer codes. I am entering these codes into my phone, but nothing is happening. When I call the entered number, I get the typical Verizon lady saying "The call cannot be completed as dialed..."

I specifically have used a code from [this link](http://www.usoftphone.com/t136616.html) (this addresses the problem I am having) and have tried multiple others from [here](http://a.com.pk/samsung-sgh-600-sgh-2100-tips-tricks-n-unlock-secret-codes/)*, but all give that same problem. Is there something that I am missing? Do I have to be a super user or something along those lines?

*Note: I know these may not be specific to my device, but some of these look to be universal regardless of manufacturer or model.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't trust such a list of secret codes, simply because secret codes are not only device specific but mostly app specific.

Secret Codes are generally defined by the applications installed on the device.
If you want to have a valid list of secret codes available on your device, you should use an automated secret codes crawler.

I recently developped an Open Source app that crawls AndroidManifest.xml files on your device to found secret codes, and allows you to execute the secret codes available on your device.
You can get it on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.simon.marquis.secretcodes) or on the GitHub repository [Android-Secret Codes](https://github.com/SimonMarquis/Android-SecretCodes).

But keep in mind that sometimes, secret codes are just executing themselves silently (without visual hint)

Comment: Not all "secret codes" are app specific, see: [supplementary service codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_codes_for_supplementary_services). They can be devided into generic (GSM) codes, provider/carrier-specific codes, manufacturer/device-specific codes, and "software-specific" codes (ROM/apps). Does your app cover them all (maybe except for the 3rd group, as that might be difficult)?

Comment: Sure, I forgot this aspect. As far as I know, "Secret Codes" are only app specific, and triggered by the system if they are registered in AndroidManifest.xml files. When I talk about Android Secret Codes, I'm refering to this: TelephonyIntents.SECRET_CODE_ACTION, and codes that starts with `*#*#` and ends with `#*#*`. But I'm aware that lots of others secret codes can be triggerred at a different level like USSD codes. By the way, I don't known any way of crawling these codes...

Comment: Thanks for the update, Simon! I wasn't aware there's an API element named by that. From this it's clear what you refer to by the term, which somehow "voids" my claims. "Secret Codes" obviously is not a term with a clear definition :)

Answer (score -1):

Just enter these codes in dial pad. The moment you type the last # key it will automatically open a window with information.(No need of hitting dial button)
These codes have been confirmed working on Galaxy S4 models.

1. *#06# IMEI number
2. *#0*# Test screen
3. *#0283# Audio loopback
4. *#2663# Firmware and Update versions
5. *#12580*369# Software and Hardware info
6. *#0228# Battery Status
7. *#2263# RF Band selection
8. *#9090# Service Mode
9. *#7284# UART MODEM PDA
10. *#8736364# Update Settings
11. *#7353# QUICK TEST MENU

Note: NONE OF THESE CODES WORK on Android 4.3!

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from the 2nd link in the original post.  It doesn't answer the question of how to properly enter these codes on a given handset.

Comment: Edited.Actually this is not a copy paste from the second link. This is confirmed working code on S4

Comment: Working on GT-I9505 for sure, not sure about verison variant.

Comment: They don't work on Verizon phones.

Comment: Yes, I can verify that, These DO NOT work on Verizon SCH-I545

Answer (score -1):

No the codes work with sch-i545 vrufng6. Only need to be roooted and change efs/carrier hidden menu disable to enable thats all

Comment: Can you explain how to do this?